# memcache in GAE disappears after being fetched

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

This doesn't seem right, when I do a

```
memcache.add('key', data, 3600)
```

and a:

```
memcache.get('key')
```

I get the results back correctly.  However, if I call

```
memcache.get('key)
```

again right afterwards, it is no longer in the memcache.  It seems to disappear right after being fetched once everytime.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Under the dev_appserver, or when deployed? What version of the SDK?

Comment: What do you mean by "right afterwards"? In the same request or from a different request?

Comment: I believe it is release 1.6.5

Comment: It is from a different request